# Unable to copy symbols from this device Using iOS 9.2.1 Xcode is 7.2

Tags: ios, iphone

Could not resize “/private/var/folders/_5/jhpy2pns35n0kljwt0l08q_40000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A Document Being Saved By Xcode 3)/dyld_shared_cache_armv7s” (No space left on device)

Has anyone figured out how to solve this issue? I am trying to set up an iPhone 6s with Xcode, and this just started happening. I tried reinstalling Xcode, but that did nothing.

Comment: I've never had this issue.  But I would check to see how much free space you have on the iphone.

Comment: Check the space on your mac

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, I had lots of free space on my iPhone but it was claiming no space left on device.

I hadn't thought that the memory on my Mac would affect this but once I deleted a few files the app downloaded to my device correctly.

I would recommend:

- Make sure your device and mac have enough memory
- Clean XCode
- Reset XCode

The combination of all of these fixed the issue for me.

Credit to @Vinícius Albino in the comments for getting me to this answer

Answer (score 0):

I did try everything. And finally realized I had to reboot my mac to make it work. This is still (unfortunatly) more often than not a step we need to make when things go wrong before further research